# Translating content within the swiper causes images to disappear

Tags: r, shiny, swiper.js

I have an image and some graphics inside a swiper. In addition, I have text content in all the sliders. However, when I translate the language, the images and graphics disappear, although the text is translated perfectly. What happens: the text on the sliders, when translated, seems to reset the slider (it goes back to the first slider and makes the elements mentioned disappear). How can I adjust the swiper so that I can translate the text but at the same time keep the images and graphics within it and remain on the current slide (without switching to the first one as is the case)? See my adapted code:

```
library(shiny)
library(swipeR)
library(shiny.i18n)
library(shinyWidgets)

i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = 'translations/translation.json')

js <- '
function updateChart(chart, value1) {
  var option = {
    series: [
      {
        type: "gauge",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        splitNumber: 10,
        data: [
          {
            value: value1,
            name: "Opportunities",
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#dd4b50"
            },
            pointer: {
              length: "100%",
              itemStyle: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#020202"
              }
            },
            title: {
              offsetCenter: ["0", "20%"]
            },
            detail: {
              offsetCenter: ["0", "36%"],
              backgroundColor: "#dd4b50",
              color: "#f2f2f2",
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: "Lato",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "#020202",
              borderRadius: 5,
              width: 32,
              height: 20
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  chart.setOption(option);
}

// Função para obter o valor do slider e atualizar o gráfico
function updateSlider(chart) {
  let value1 = Number($("#slider2").val());
  updateChart(chart, value1);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $div = $("<div id=\\\"chartid1\\\" style=\\\"height: 410px;\\\">XXX</div>");
  var div = $div.get(0);
  var chart1;

  $("#dropButton_state").on("shown.bs.dropdown", function () {
  
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var $container = $("#toBeAppended");
      if($container.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $container.append($div);
        chart1 = echarts.init(div);
        updateSlider(chart1);
        $("#dropButton_state").off("shown.bs.dropdown");
      }
    }); 

  });
  
  // Adiciona um evento input ao slider para atualizar o gráfico quando o valor do slider mudar
  $("#slider2").on("change", function () {
    updateSlider(chart1);
  });
  
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(

  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.0/echarts.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  tags$input(id = "slider2", type = "number", value = "50"),
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "switchlanguage1",
    label = "Language",
    choices = c("English", "Español", "中国")
  ),
  
  dropdownButton(
    
    inputId = "dropButton",
    width = 600,
    
    div(
      uiOutput("outSwiper")
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # trasnlate
  # i18n languages----
  observeEvent(input$switchlanguage1, {
    
    if (input$switchlanguage1 == "English") {
      
      shiny.i18n::update_lang("en")
      
    } else if (input$switchlanguage1 == "Español") {
      
      shiny.i18n::update_lang("es")
      
    } else if (input$switchlanguage1 == "中国") {
      
      shiny.i18n::update_lang("ch")
      
    }
    
  })
  
  # swiper inside dropdown()
  output$outSwiper <- renderUI({
    swipeR(
      id = "carouselSwotContainer1",
      wrapper = swipeRwrapper(
        
        div(
          id = "toBeAppended",
          "Some text 1"
        ),
        
        div(
          i18n$t("Some text 2")
        )
        
      ),
      initialSlide = 1,
      bulletsSize = NULL,
      paginationColor = "navy",
      navigationColor = "navy",
      loop = FALSE,
      height = "310px",
      width = "90%",
      effect = "cube",
      speed = 1000,
      rewind = FALSE
    )
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`JSON`:

```
{
  
  "languages": ["en", "es", "ch"],
  
  "translation": [
    {
      "en": "Some text 2",
      "es": "Algunos textos 2",
      "ch": "部分文字 2"
    }
    
  ]
  
}
```

I used the `shiny.i18n` package to do the translation, but as I described, the images and graphics disappear when I translate for the first time. I've tried changing the structure of the code (passing the objects and functions of the graphic to the server, for example), but nothing works. I've also tried an `ifelse()` conditional to translate "manually" but it also affects the swiper, having the same behavior as if I were using `i18n$t("...")`. I need it so that when I change the language (no matter how many times and to any language (alternately), the images and graphics in the swiper are retained in their entirety, just as they are when I open it for the first time without having translated anything yet.

**I need to prevent the propagation of any update within the swiper, preventing it from resetting the images and graphics and returning to the initial slider.**

Comment: You have a typo: `div(id = "toBeAppende")` (last `d` missing). Not sure if the problem is there but it can't be helping finding the root cause!

Comment: @delightfulmemento Hi, I've removed this part of the code, it's irrelevant in this example. Thanks for noticing!